# Could a Notice: undefined index error in php be fixed this way?

Tags: php

I have been tasked to complete a project that three former students of my school have been working on, and have no way of contacting the first two working on it, and since it's up and running right now I have no way of testing the system against anything else than reality which somtimes might not be the best test server. Right now I have an error in the error report script that the first two wrote, it is a Notice: Undefined index on line 73-75 the lines looks as follows:

```
$text .= $t['file'] . "\n";
$text .= $t['line'] . "\n";
$text .= print_r($t['file'], 1) . "\n";
```

Line 72 looks like this:

```
$text .= ((isset($t['type']) && isset($t['object'])) ? print_r($t['object'], true) . $t['type'] . $t['function'] : $t['function']) . "\n";
```

So what I wonder is if it the problem would be fixed if added an if statement on line 72 like this:

```
$text .= if((isset($t['type']) && isset($t['object'])) ? print_r($t['object'], true) . $t['type'] . $t['function'] : $t['function']) . "\n";
```

Comment: That will not fix your problem.  The `(tests) ?` portion of the line is already an `if` statement.  See this page for details: http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples (not my page)

Comment: Don't use the ternary operator for complex conditions like this. It's  not worth the maintainability tradeoff for being slick and having less lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better check will be the next:

```
if( isset( $t['file'] ) ) {
    $text .= $t['file'] . "\n";
}

if( isset( $t['line'] ) ) {
    $text .= $t['line'] . "\n";
}

if( isset( $t['file'] ) ) {
    $text .= print_r($t['file'], 1) . "\n";
}
```

This code is more easy to read.

**But** I recommend to detect the reason why indexes are undefined. This can be result ща other more seriously logical error.

Never suppress notices and warnings in this way if these notices and warnings appeared after long period of good work. First You have to detect why they appeared.

Comment: This problem does only exist when using the logging function built but when printing the error on screen as the debugging does there I don't get this error which atleast to my understanding would mean that there is somthing wrong with the logging and not something else in this case.

Comment: Yes, I understand how did you get this notices, see my comment about closures in other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a ternary operator:

```
$var = (a == b) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

if a == b then $var = 'yes' else $var = 'no'

then

```
((isset($t['type']) && isset($t['object'])) ? print_r($t['object'], true) . $t['type'] . $t['function'] : $t['function']) . "\n";
```

is the same as

```
if (isset($t['type']) && isset($t['object'])) {
    $text .= print_r($t['object'], true) . $t['type'] . $t['function'];
} else {
    $text .= $t['function'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that explains exactly how they made that, now i just have to understand why they did it that way and what is wrong with the rest :)

Comment: They didn't check `$t['file']` and `$t['file']` because they assumed that keys `file` and `line` will be always in array. But closures (this is a relatively new feature in PHP) can change this postulate. I don't know if there is other way to receive backtrace item without `file` and `line` keys.

Comment: ok so they (as I...) assumed that file and line would never be empty because if they where it would be hard if not impossible to backtrace it which would render the logging useless, but if that is true then there is also some error that would be logged but not with all the information if I where to do as suggested in the other answer. Which would give me a better chance of solving what is causing the logging to try and log something.